How to update the content of gr.dropdown drop-down box in gradio
I am a beginner in gradio. The items in my gr.dropdown come from all the keys in a dictionary. When the user is operating, he can change the key and value added to the dictionary. At this time, I want the drop-down box to update the latest keys at the same time. How can I do it?
............................................................................................................................................................................
    dropdown1 = gr.Dropdown(choices=list(dropdown_options.keys()), label="report1")            
    dropdown2 = gr.Dropdown(choices=list(dropd
    own_options.keys()), label="report2")           
    submit_report = gr.Button("submit")
    def create_dropdown(options, label):
      return gr.Dropdown(choices=list(dropdown_options.keys()),              label=label,interactive=True)
    # Using state variables to store drop-down options
    dropdown_options_state = gr.State(value=getdict())
.....
    dropdown1 = create_dropdown(dropdown_options_state.value, "report1")
    dropdown2 = create_dropdown(dropdown_options_state.value, "report2")
    submit_report = gr.Button("sumbit
")


gr.State doesn't seem to work
